# Adding ResourceDictionary to Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries (Avalonia UI)

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia, mergeddictionaries

I want to add resources through code, but I can't do it.

In WPF, I would have done that:

```
Application.Current.Resources.Clear();
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(
    new Uri(@"Resources\Style\light.xaml", UriKind.Relative)) as ResourceDictionary);
```

But Avalonia doesn't have an `Application.LoadComponent`.

I try to do it, but it doesn't work:

```
Application.Current?.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current?.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add( new ResourceInclude
{
    Source = new Uri(@"/Assets/icons/LightIcons.axaml", UriKind.Relative)
});
```

If you know how to do this, please help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it's the right thing to do:

```
Application.Current?.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
Application.Current?.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceInclude
    {
        Source = new Uri("avares://MyApplication/Assets/icons/DarkIcons.axaml")
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).